# Pass rvalue by reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I am struggling to turn this piece of code into a one-liner:

```
std::string filename = "cats";
std::shared_ptr<bmd2::Bmd2Dataset> ptr (new bmd2::Bmd2Dataset(filename, bmd2::File::FM_WRITE));
bmd2::bmd2Session::getInstance().addDataset(ptr);
```

The above works great -- but can I call addDataset without creating the lvalues (lines 1 + 2)?

Here is the declaration of addDataset():

```
int addDataset(std::shared_ptr<bmd2::Bmd2Dataset> &) throw (bmd2Exception);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bmd2::bmd2Session::getInstance().addDataset(
   std::make_shared<bmd2::Bmd2Dataset>("cats", bmd2::File::FM_WRITE)
);
```

One statementer. `:)`

> Interesting. For learning purposes, can you tell me if you can accomplish this without the make_shared() function call?

You can, using C++11's brace initialization syntax. Assuming `addDataset` isn't a template and has `std::shared_ptr<bmd2::Bmd2Dataset>` as its parameter,

```
bmd2::bmd2Session::getInstance().addDataset(
   { new bmd2::Bmd2Dataset("cats", bmd2::File::FM_WRITE) }
);
```

**UPDATE:** Oops. So `addDataset()` actually accepts an *l-value* reference <sub>why didn't you say so immediately?</sub>. `addDataset()`'s parameter can't bind to r-value parameters, which in the two above examples are. To solve this, you can either:

- Make `addDataset()`'s parameter a `const` reference

  ```
  int addDataset(const std::shared_ptr<bmd2::Bmd2Dataset> &) throw (bmd2Exception);
  //             ^^^^^
  ```

  Do this if you don't need to modify the passed `shared_ptr` argument (i.e. modifying it so it points to another object).
- Use your older method, <strike>though passing directly `"cat"` into the the `new` expression</strike>. **UPDATE:** Use `std::make_shared`!

  ```
  auto ptr = std::make_shared<bmd2::Bmd2Dataset>("cats", bmd2::File::FM_WRITE);
  bmd2::bmd2Session::getInstance().addDataset(ptr);
  // ptr might now point to some other object
  ```

  Do this if you want the passed argument's (`ptr`) value to be changed (i.e. after the call it might now point to a new object).

Comment: Interesting.  For learning purposes, can you tell me if you can accomplish this without the make_shared() function call?

Comment: I tried your example and the compiler gives the error that the addDataset() function is not called with the correct arguments:

Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:
int addDataset(std::shared_ptr<bmd2::Bmd2Dataset> &)'.  My code, on the other hand, does not produce this error.  I updated my question to show you the declaration of the addDataset() function.

Comment: This was such an excellent answer.  Thank you SO much.  Bless your soul :D

Comment: @jakeliquorblues You're welcome. (Though in stackoverflow, a much better way to show your gratitude is to continue to give great questions and answers.) `:)`